# start spss with opening specific syntax

Tags: spss

I want SPSS to open a specific syntax-file when starting up. I have managed to open a blank syntax-file when starting up, by going to Edit -> Options and clicking on "Open syntax window at startup" in the General settings. However I'd like to start a specific syntax-file containing code I usually need.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Mac or Windows, open a command (terminal on Mac) window. At the prompt, go the directory where you have installed SPSS (assuming it isn't on your PATH) and invoke the SPSS executable with the added command line argument of the file name. For example, on Windows:

```
C:\>CD \<path to SPSS>
stats C:\MyPath\MyFile.sps
```

on Mac:

```
cd /Applications/mypath/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/MacOS
./stats /MyPath/MyFile.sps
```

You can do this with a syntax, SAV, or SPV file.